# What is the difference between *p,**p, ***p in pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I have confusion in above pointers in C Language what the difference between them and in what situation they are suitable to use..

Comment: Oh..boy.. Did you search on stackoverflow ?

Comment: that would be equivalent to "what is C language?"

Comment: The first two are valid, but for the last one you may as well be swearing in C.

Comment: *p is a pointer, **p is a pointer to a pointer, ...

Comment: `*p` = the programmer is writing normal code. `**p` = the programmer is writing special code. `***p` = the programmer is a special snowflake.

Comment: I have searched but couldn't understand the purpose of these pointers...

Comment: Don't use them then?

Comment: Their purpose is to facilitate the fundamental theorem of software engineering. Heck, C allows you to use even higher order pointers.

Comment: If you're struggling with pointers and memory management and stuff you should just keep practicing with them until you get that "aha" moment.

Answer (score 3):

`*p` is a pointer, **this means that it holds an address of a value or a block of reserved memory**, this would be used if you want to retain a block of memory where your values are in.

`**p` is a pointer to a pointer, **this means that it holds an address that holds an address of a value or a block of reserved memory**, this would be used if you want to pass a pointer that gets its memory allocated in a different function.

`***p` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, **this means that it holds an address that holds an address that holds an address of a value or a block of reserved memory**, I don't even want to know why this would be used.

Comment: A pointer variable holds the address of some other variable. A value doesn't have an address, a variable has.

Comment: @artm a value with an address is a variable, the pointer holds that address.

Answer (score 1):

`*p` - pointer, that can point to memory location, variable

`**p` - pointer, wich holds location of another pointer, wich holds memory location

`***p` - pointer, that point to **p

Answer (score 0):

*p is simply a pointer to a variable and p store the address of the variable.
**p is a pointer to a pointer to a variable and p stores the address of the pointer.
***p is a pointer to a pointer to pointer to a variable and p stoers the address of the second pointer.

Comment: Pointers don't necessarily point to variables.